# Google Script - onEdit(e) to trigger specific cell change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently using the below script to trigger an automatic cell edit. However, as a script basically runs every time any cell on the worksheet is edited, I wonder if there is a way to modify it so that it only works when let's say a cell  B24 is edited or a range of cells from B24 - B30 are then trigger the script. It seems like an `onEdit (e)` function could be an answer but I'm struggling to modify the code accordingly. Would you guys be so kind and help?

```
function myfunction() {

var app = SpreadsheetApp;
var targetSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ABC");
targetSheet.getRange(154,2).setValue("Bingo");
}
```

When using the below `onEdit(e)` I keep receiving an error message `" target sheet not defined"`

```
function onEdit(e) {

var range = e.range;
var spreadSheet = e.source;
var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
var column = range.getColumn();
var row = range.getRow();

if(sheetName == 'Harmonogram wpłat' && column == 2 && row == 24)
{

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().gatSheetByName('ABC').getRange('B154').setValue('Bingo');

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, the error is due to the typo in the last line of your code.

```
gatSheetByName('ABC')
```

should be

```
getSheetByName('ABC')
```

See if that helps?

Comment: Thank you JPV for your comment, exactly it was a typo issue, I should have been more careful ;) Have a great rest of the day!

Answer (score 3):

### Modification points:

1. You have a typo as the other answer has already mentioned. It should be [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)) and not `gatSheetByName(name)`.
2. You want to execute the script when a cell in the range B24 - B30 is edited. To achieve that you need to modify the `if` condition to include that range:

   ```
   if(sheetName == 'Harmonogram wpłat' && column == 2 && row > 23 && row<31)
   ```
3. `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` can be replaced by `spreadSheet` since `e.source` is exactly the same thing.

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {    
  var range = e.range;
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();    
  if(sheetName == 'Harmonogram wpłat' && column == 2 && row > 23 && row<31){
       spreadSheet.getSheetByName('ABC').getRange('B154').setValue('Bingo');
  }   
}
```

Comment: stupid me, thank you for pointing out the typo and thank you for sharing your tip regarding the range, it also was helpful :) Good day to you Sir!